# Aggregate function outside pivot

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to use a aggregate function outside the pivot?Am trying to do that. Here I write a query which contain an aggregate function outside Pivot it wasn't work.

```
select id,**sum(num),**jan,feb
from ( select id, num, month(date) as date, val
......
.......
)p
pivot(sum(val) for date in ([jan],[feb])) as pivotanble
```

if i omit the ***sum(num)*** or only use num it is working otherwise not. What will be the solution?

initial input

```
      id   date       num    val

       1---2001.06.03--2------3

       2---2002.02.05--10-----5

       3----2002.02.09---4----2
```

Expected

```
          JAN FEB MAR... year

           0--- 8 --0  -- 14
```

year will be given as an input here year=2002

Comment: Can you add sample data and an expected output please? Your question is not very clear at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please refer below URL

[Pivoting Without Aggregation](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/pivoting-without-aggregation)

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you could just add up all the monthly values to get the yearly value:

```
SELECT
  id,
  Jan,
  Feb,
  ...
  Year = Jan + Feb + ...
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    num,
    date = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, date), 3)
  FROM ...
  WHERE ...
) AS s
PIVOT (
  SUM(num)
  FOR date IN (Jan, Feb, ...)
) AS p
;
```

But you could also calculate the yearly value beforehand in the subselect, using `SUM() OVER ()`:

```
SELECT
  id,
  Jan,
  Feb,
  ...
  Year
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    num,
    date = LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, date), 3),
    Year = SUM(num) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(DATENAME(MONTH, date), 3))
  FROM ...
  WHERE ...
) AS s
PIVOT (
  SUM(num)
  FOR date IN (Jan, Feb, ...)
) AS p
;
```